# New android L Navigation Drawer design

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-5.0-lollipop

Currently application rolling out with android L design. I'm impressed with that navigation drawer part. For example they are implemented in following application. Sliding Explorer, Today Calendar etc. Can someone explain how to design and implement that navigation drawer!

Comment: Where did you see those applications ? on google play ?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26230417/animation-actionbar-material-design