# Animation actionBar material design

Tags: android, animation, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

how you can do this kind of animations in the ActionBar?

[Example animation actionBar material design](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/videos/DelightfulDetails_WellCrafted_v01_large_xhdpi.webm)

Answer (score 5):

Currently there isn't public API to obtain this.

You can try this library:

https://github.com/markushi/android-ui

Answer (score 4):

I have used [***balysv/material-menu***](https://github.com/balysv/material-menu) library and implemented successfully.

[***ActionView By Markushi***](https://github.com/markushi/android-ui) requires  **API level 14+**  but  ***material-menu by balysv***  can be used with `ActionBarSherLock` also with animation customization.

Here you have four icon states:

BURGER, ARROW, X, CHECK. You can use (X, CHECK) for delete operation and (BURGER, ARROW) for navigation drawer.

[image]

One more feature that i like is **pressed circle animation**. Here we have choice between  pressed circle animation and non-pressed circle animation.

You can have full control of animation while sliding a drawer like this,

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Android Support Library v7's ActionBarDrawerToggle has that animation.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html

Here is the instruction to add support library v7 to your project.
https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Gabriele Mariotti's answer.

You might try to replace android.R.id.home with the `ActionView` from the library he mentioned.

Find the view and replace it:

```
private void replaceHomeView(Activity activity){
    View homeView;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            Resources resources = activity.getResources();
            int id = resources.getIdentifier("android:id/home", null, null);
            homeView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(id);
        } else {
            homeView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.home);
        }
    replace(homeView);

}
```

Remove and replace home icon `ImageView`:

```
private replace(View home){
   ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
   int homeIndex = parent.indexOfChild(view);
   ActionView newHome = new ActionView(home.getContext));
   newHome.setId(home.getId());
   parent.removeView(home);
   parent.addView(newHome, homeIndex);
}
```

**Note:** I haven't tested this myself.